# Arcpy crashes in loop geoprocessing (general behaviour)

Tags: python, arcpy

I have several standalone scripts that create a list of shapefiles to process (or coverages in one of the scripts).  Sometimes my script crashes after it processes three files, sometimes ten, sometimes with just one to go. In some cases, it's quite complex operations, but sometimes, it's just a simple `arcpy.Union_analysis(inShp, outShp)` or with `CalculateField_management()`.

It seems totally random because I just delete the outputs before restarting my scripts and it may or may not work the next time. Eventually it works, sometimes on the first try, but other times, I could have to retry it 2 or 5 or 10 times.

Any ideas what could cause this?
Should I clean or delete something from memory that could cause a crash?

Thanks!

Comment: Could you provide a Python script sample that is causing you problems?

Comment: You could add a try/except handler to give you more information on the error. See the Python [Errors and Exceptions](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/errors.html) section

Comment: Here's some: This one [batch convert .e00 into shp in structured directories](http://fgcartographix.com/scripts/conversion_cadastre.py). That one takes several points (users/train stations) and [create a "service area" from a certain point density](http://fgcartographix.com/scripts/desserte_gares.py) and the last one [compares each service area to the others to determine overlaps](http://fgcartographix.com/scripts/chevauchement.py). They never crashes at the same place or with the same tool (Dissolve, Select, ...). Thanks!

Comment: It's maddening... I added Errors/Exceptions Handling (with the traceback module to get python and ArcPy message). I simply put all my code inside my loop in the "try:" and my loop increment as well. When there's a error, my counter don't increment because the "i=i+1" is after when the error occured. So, when the loop restart, my "i" is the same as previous and it restart processing the same files that cause the error... And then it works! See this [screenshot](http://fgcartographix.com/scripts/screen.jpg), Green, first try, yellow, 2nd and blue, ok and processing the next...

Comment: Could that be that the script is too quick and arcpy outputs necessary for the next step arent already available? Clearly the code itself isn't a problem? Maybe adding a "time.sleep(1)" could help?

Comment: Time delay failed! ;)
On that second [screenshot](http://fgcartographix.com/scripts/screenshot2.jpg) from another script, we see that the first error occurred at line 170 executing a Dissolve (in blue). That script don't use a counter so it passes on the next file. The second error occurred at line 116 executing a Select (in green). So that means that the first one passes the line 116 without error previously. At the end, about 1/2 of the files were treated correctly, even though it worked till the end the last time I used it... I DON'T UNDERSTAND!!

Comment: are you running your scripts in the console or from another application??. I have found that some scripts run without crashing outside of arc but not from the console in arc. If you are using the console try turning of the add results to display and maybe set the enviroment to "results are temp by default".From your screenshot it looks like shapefiles are used, I wounder if it would make a difference if you used a filegeodatabase instead. good luck!!

Comment: The script does not run from Arc. It's call from a command prompt >python conversion.py... Didn't try filegdb since for now, I need shapefiles but eventually, everything will be exported to a fgdb. I ended modifying my script and made a while loop. It lists the .e00, skip the file when there's an error (simple try/except), transfer them in a temp folder when it's succesfull and then, re-list the remaining .e00 to convert. The last time I did it, it took 7 iterations to convert all my 600 .e00. At least, it's working.

Answer (score 1):

Are you creating any featureclasses in memory? Because the inconsistency could be down to not deleting an in-memory fc. If you are, try something like:

```
    if arcpy.Exists(fc):
        del fc
```

after each iteration of your loop. Hope this helps!

Comment: You'd likely need to use arcpy.Delete_management() as opposed to del

Comment: I used Delete_management() for the output of all tool that create another file as output and del for "in_memory" datasets. The two tools that cause much problem are "arcpy.FeatureClassToShapefile_conversion(inFeaturePolygon, outFolder)" and "arcpy.Project_management(inFeatureClassPolygon, outFeatureClassPolygon, outCoordSys)". The thing is that since it's looping, the values of my variables are reassigned each time... Of course, if "Foncier Quebec" (Quebec Land Parcels) could just give us anything except .e00...